# How do I fix output from command-line arguments to printing out the correct integers?

Tags: c, atoi

```
#define N 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *a = malloc(sizeof(N));
    int i;

    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        *(a++) = atoi(argv[i]);
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < N) {
        printf("%d ", *(a++));
        i++;
    }
}
```

I'm confused on why my output is all 0s. I'm not really sure how to fix it since i am new to command-line arguments / pointers. A background for this program is that it takes in integers, then is supposed to convert them from strings to integers using atoi then print the new array back out using pointer arithmetic.

Comment: This should segfault if you supply any more than 4 arguments.  `int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * N)` or `int *a = calloc(N, sizeof(int))`

Comment: Don't increment a pointer if you malloc it. Use array syntax.

Comment: @Tibrogargan When I entered the 10 inputs I didn't get any seg fault. Just an Output of 0s

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean I'm supposed to use pointer arithmetic to solve this, If I cant use malloc then what would I use?

Comment: Create an array of ints and use an int pointer to point to the array... (pseudo) ... `int numbers[N]; ... for(int *a = numbers; a < numbers + argc; a++) { ...`.  (But either way, fix the malloc, you're only allocating 4 ints, not N)

Comment: It's probably not segfaulting at the moment because you're probably being lucky and getting allocated an entire page of memory that you're not using most of.  Since this is a very simple application you're not overwriting anything important ... just random unused memory.  Just because it's not crashing yet doesn't mean you're doing it right.

Comment: You need two pointers. I've written a long answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with this.

sizeof(N) gives the size of an integer constant (probably 4 bytes). What you mean is malloc(N * sizeof(int)); But there's not much point using malloc if N is mall and you know it at compile time. You want to malloc argc ints. Then the program will scale to millions of commandline arguments, assuming the shell allows such a long line to be entered.

Then when you malloc a pointer, you need to hang onto it. Don't increment it. If you want a travelling pointer, use two pointers, a and ptr. a points to the buffer and "owns" it, ptr is a temporary that moves along. However array syntax a[i] is almost always preferable to travelling pointers.

Then the final while will print garbage values if argc is less than N. that might be want you want in a learning exercise / exploratory programming, but not what you normally hope to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Against my better judgement, here's a solution for your homework.  Please pay attention to the following:

- It's not casting the return value of malloc
- It's testing the return value of malloc is non NULL
- It's freeing the memory it allocates
- It uses a variety of pointer arithmetic
- It's correcting the use of argv[0]
- It's correcting the misuse of argc
- It's using a "yoda condition" to eliminate the possibility the compiler is stupid
- It will still segfault if you supply any more than `N` arguments

```c
#define N 10
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *numbers;

    if (NULL != (numbers = malloc(N * sizeof *numbers))) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++) {
            *(numbers + i) = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
        }

        for(int* a = numbers; a < (numbers + (argc - 1)); a++) {
            printf("%d ", *(a));
        }
        free(numbers);
    }
}
```